# python main() not executing in shell

Tags: python, shell, python-idle

i am trying to run my flatten(li) function in main but its not running when i run the module. but when i type in "flatten(li)" in shell it is working. any ideas? thanks!

```
li = [0, 2, [[2, 3], 8, 100, None, [[None]]], -2]

def flatten(li):
     i = 0
     while i < len(li):
         "only execute if the element is a list"
         while isinstance(li[i], list):
             """taking the element at index i and sets it as the
                i'th part of the list. so if l[i] contains a list
                it is then unrolled or 'unlisted'"""
             li[i:i + 1] = li[i]
         i += 1

    for element in li:  
         if not element and not isinstance(element, int):
         li.remove(element)

    return li

def main():
    flatten(li)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: you see nothing because you print nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the output. I'm not sure what you expect to see, but something like this is what you want:

```
li = [0, 2, [[2, 3], 8, 100, None, [[None]]], -2]


def flatten(li):
    i = 0
    while i < len(li):
        while isinstance(li[i], list):
            li[i:i + 1] = li[i]
        i += 1

    for element in li:
        if not element and not isinstance(element, int):
            li.remove(element)

    return li


def main():
    flat = flatten(li)
    print(flat)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: cool thanks so much! how come i dont need to print if i just type flatten(li) in shell? also, is my way of documentation proper?

Comment: When you type `flatten(li)` you're calling the `flatten` function, which returns `li`. By default your shell is printing the returned value. When you call `main`it's calling `flatten`, which returns `li` to `main`, but the `main` function isn't doing anything with that object. `main` then returns `None` to the shell.

Answer (score 0):

It works, of course -- you just do not print anything, so you do not see anything. Try to add `print` call:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print(li)
```

Comment: cool thanks so much! how come i dont need to print if i just type flatten(li) in shell? also, is my way of documentation proper?

Comment: If you run things from python shell, it prints out automatically what called function returned -- for your convenience.

Comment: And no, the way you document the code is not proper. Use comments instead (`# here goes some comment`). The way you try to document things  (docstrings) is used only for functions, classes and modules.